# PHP MAILER - EMAIL SENDING

Tags: php

I want to send a confirmation mail to an user who is trying to register. Iam using PHP Mailer for sending mails. Here is my code:

```
require_once("PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");

        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->Host = "localhost";
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;// turn on SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = "root";// SMTP username
        $mail->Password = "";// SMTP password
        $mail->SetLanguage("en","PHPMailer/language");

        //compose mail
        $mail->From = "admin@localhost.com";
        $mail->FromName = "Cinema Admin";
        $mail->AddAddress($_POST['email']);
        $mail->AddReplyTo("admin@localhost.com", "Cinema Admin");
        $mail->Subject = 'Your confirmation link here';
        $mail->Body = "Your confirmation link\r\n";
        $mail->Body .= "Click on this link to activate your sccount\r\n";
        $mail->Body .= "http://localhost/user.login_plugin/confirm.php?passkey=$confirm_code"; 

        //send mail
        if (!$mail->Send())
        {
            echo "Message was not sent <p>";
            echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            exit;
        }

        echo "Message has been sent";
```

When I execute the file,it says

```
Message was not sent

Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
```

Could anyone suggest me for sending mails from localhost to the registered user's emailid.
I had searched with few titles regarding "ending emails" in stack overflow, but couldn't find any solution from any posts.

Thank You in advance

Comment: Check your smtp authentication , or else don't use smtp

Comment: Could you tell me how to check SMTP authentication, Iam using Windows 7

Comment: do you have a mailserver set up locally?

Comment: NO.. I don't have anything setup for any mail server. Could you please help me how to? Iam using WINDOWS 7

Comment: Is there any solution for sending mails from localhost. I have seen many posts in stack overflow, no one were satisfied with the answers regarding sending mails.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try remove the smtp part? From your comment , you do not have mail server setup.

```
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->SetLanguage("en","PHPMailer/language"); // remove smtp things
```

Comment: I have removed all smtp things as according to your suggestion and now when I execute it says : Mailer Error: Could not instantiate mail function.

Answer (score 0):

You must need a SMTP details in order to send an email using SMTP, For example if you want to setup SMTP using gmail,

```
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;         // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";        // sets the prefix to the servier
    $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
    $mail->Port       = 587;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
    $mail->Username   = "yourusername@gmail.com";  // GMAIL username
    $mail->Password   = "yourpassword";            // GMAIL password
```

If you don't want use SMTP, you can called default mail function

```
$mail->IsMail(); //Sets Mailer to send message using PHP mail() function.
```

Comment: It cannot be only gmail, It can be anything like gmail or yahoo or hotmail etc., An email should be sent to a user registered email from my localhost.